# Is it possible to design a game in Blender?

Tags: unity

I was wondering if it´s possible to design a game in blender?

For example, can you design a level in Blender then export it to Unity?

It would seem to be easier to do it that way since Blender is dedicated to modelling and the interface in Unity looks quite complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You can model every element of your game in Blender then export them into Unity, or any other game engine. The game itself would still have to be coded in Unity.

Blender 2.79, the current version, even has an internal game engine allowing you to design games that works in Blender itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One more thing... Should I use subdiv. modifier when making game objects? :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea, I've never made a game in Blender myself. Also, it would seem that the game engine won't be in future version of Blender, starting from 2.8, since there are now way better engines to make games and Blender is a modelling software at heart. You can accept my answer by clicking the check-mark under the voting arrows to the left, it will give me reputation which is how the economy of the site works. You can take the [tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about how StackExchange works.